# Cut connection time by optimizing code for speed

Tags: sql, vb.net, optimization, load-time, data-management

I'm trying to optimize a small patch of code that's connecting to our servers over and over again. To start off, here's the patch of code

```
Dim sale as Sale()
With sale
    If .CustomerID > 0 Then
        .CustomerName = CCCustomer.SelectByID(.CustomerID).FirstNameLastName
    Else
        .CustomerName = "Cash Sale"
    End If
End With
```

So the issue is that if you have, say 50 customers that this is iterating through, it takes a long long time to get through the data, as for each customerID all you have to access the CCCustomer object, connect to the database, find the customer by ID, and then select the FirstNameLastName from the object.

My first thought was to just pull a list or array of ALL the customers right off the bat, and then match them by ID, but this seems to take even LONGER

```
Dim sale as Sale()
With sale

    Dim allCustomers() = CCCustomer.SelectAll

    If .CustomerID > 0 Then
        .CustomerName = Array.FindIndex(allCustomers, Function(c) c.CustomerID = .CustomerID)
    Else
        .CustomerName = "Cash Sale"
    End If
End With
```

(This code returns the customerId, not the names, but it still takes forever either way)

The only other option I can think of would be a complete rewrite of multiple stored procedures and updating the object to just natively hold the customers name as well as the customerID, but figured I'd check in before I go about completely ripping apart the rest of the program.

So does anyone know a good way to get a decent load time for something like this when you're pulling from a database?

Comment: Do you have a relationship defined between sale and customer? Can you eager load the customers along with the sales?

Comment: The only relationship between sales and customer is just along CustomerID. So I COULD just load the customers names along with the sales, but that would involve rewriting all of the stored procs for all of the sales, etc. Honestly, what I'd love to do would be something like 

    SELECT FirstNameLastName FROM allCustomers WHERE CustomerID = .CustomerID

Comment: Why do you think the first sample is iterating over the customers? why isn't it just select that single customer with a SQL `where` statement?

Comment: Sorry that was a bad explanation on my part - it's not iterating through the customer it's CREATING the customer object. So if you had a situation where sale 1, 2, 5, and 9 are all made to CustomerA, for each sale it says 'Okay, create the object for CustomerA, what's his firstnamelastname?', and then again on sale 2, and sale 5, and sale 9. Since my customer object is so large, it bogs down the whole process when you have to create the customer each time you need his firstnamelastname

Comment: Kind of adding to that - it also hits the database each time to search for the customer... so for each sale it goes "What's the customer ID? Connect to database. Get Customer. Create object. Get FirstNameLastName" --- which isn't bad for 2 or 3, but if you hit 50-100 sales, it's a mess.